# Add a dynamic field based on a substring in the middle of a field

Tags: solr

As indicated in the [Solr documentation](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Dynamic_fields), only one * is allowed at either the beginning or the end of a dynamic field.

What if I wanted to add a dynamic field based on a substring in the middle of a field? How could I accomplish this given the above limitation?

e.g. If I have fields called `myIdx0`, `anotherIdx1`, and `someIdx0`; would it be possible to create a dynamic field that would match these values since `<dynamicField name="*Idx*"  type="int" indexed="true"  stored="true"/>` is not valid?

Why was this constraint added? Previous versions of Solr did not have this limitation. I was able to track this constraint down to [this commit](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/commit/5cbf7f54c38924c19f9cdc347c729abfd7b17076#diff-ca2b07d8a1eaf45cdb5e73eba102ba38R423). However, none of the JIRA requests referenced by that commit talk about why this particular constraint was added.

Comment: Why would you want to increment an index at the back of a field? Make that kind of field `multiValued ="true"`, strip the index at the end and make the `*` at the start of the field.

Comment: @cheffe This is not a schema I have developed, I'm still learning. As such I can't say if what you suggest is appropriate in my situation but that does give me something else to look at. My main inquiry really stems around why substring matching was allowed in older versions of Solr but not in the latest version.